# Error in copy file from network share with C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis, copy

I have a line of code like this:

```
File.Copy(@"\\192.168.1.40\folder1\1.txt", Server.MapPath("/folder1/") + "1.txt", true );
```

This code works when I run my project in Visual Studio (IIS Express), but when I publish it on web server (it's in local network i.e. 192.168.1.20), it throws an exception that says access denied.

I checked permissions, nothing seems wrong.

I connected to the web server with Remote Desktop and I copied the file in Explorer without problem.

I gave the `Everyone` all permissions in 192.168.1.40.

I searched a lot, almost all of them leads to impersonation, but why it's work on local IIS Express and not on main IIS server?

Comment: Have you given the Everyone permission in the shared folder folder1?

Comment: Yes I gave it `Full Control`.